# JavaScript Promises : Deep nested context with bind(this)

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Because I'm using a prototype that has functions calling other functions in the same prototype I have to refer to that method using `this`

The Problem `this` Created:

**But because of that, I have to preserve a context to use `this` that has me forming very ugly `.bind(this)` walls.**

Here is a simplified example I made for laughs.

```
Killmyself.prototype.fireLeMissles = function () {

    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        this.anotherFunction(param).then(function(result) {

        someList.forEach(function(item) {
          this.fireLeMissles().then(function(anotherResult){
            promiseList.push(anotherResult)
          })
        },this);
        Promise.all(promiseList).then(function(promiseItem){
          childPlacesIds.forEach(function(childPlaceId) {
            //Do Other Stuff
          },this);
        });
      resolve(result);
    }.bind(this).catch(function(err){
      console.log("Yea, life sucks sometimes.")
    }));
  }.bind(this));
}

Killmyself.prototype.another = function(){
   //Other stuff
}
```

You can see because of calls to functions in the same prototype such as `this.anotherFunction(`... and `this.fireLeMissles(`... I had to do deep preservation of context,which now (in my much larger version of this) is making this code hard to work with.

**Question:**

Is this a "man up and get use to the harder aspects of JavaScript" thing - or do you seasoned developers see simple ways that deep binding like this could have been avoided?

Comment: I would use `.bnd(this)` if `nesting` is one level up else would go with the `var _this=this` and would have referred `_this` inside nested functions..

Comment: Since you tagged this with ES6, are you familiar with arrow functions?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've tried to stick with es5 since I've never thought about using babel with server side coding, but I am familiar that one of the perks of arrow functions, I believe, is that the context is implied.

Comment: Good to clarify, since you tagged ES6, I assumed you were asking for an ES6 solution. Node 4 and 5 support arrow functions and promises natively, so many people use them.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Sorry I forgot to tag es5 as well. I just assumed either I was pigeonholing myself into a poor design, or that a slicker es6 solution(which I haven't dived into yet) existed for these kind of purposes.

Comment: Linked - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46480351/104380

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using **ES6**, you can benefit from [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which preserve the context.

```
var counter = function () {
    this.count = 0;
    setInterval( () => { // arrow function
        console.log(this.count++); // context is preserved
    }, 1000)
}
var counter = new counter();
```

So, your code would become something like:

```
Killmyself.prototype.fireLeMissles = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.anotherFunction(param).then(result => {
            someList.forEach(item => {
                this.fireLeMissles().then(anotherResult => {
                    promiseList.push(anotherResult)
                });
            });
            Promise.all(promiseList).then(promiseItem => {
                childPlacesIds.forEach(childPlaceId => {
                    //Do Other Stuff
                });
            });
            resolve(result);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Yea, life sucks sometimes.")
        });
    });
}
```

For **ES5**, you can just either use `.bind` just like the way you did or you can assign `this` to something else in the function with the desired context, then use that variable inside the inner functions.

```
Killmyself.prototype.fireLeMissles = function() {
    var self = this; /// use `self` instead of `this` from now on.
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        self.anotherFunction(param).then(function(result) {
            someList.forEach(function(item) {
                self.fireLeMissles().then(function(anotherResult) {
                    promiseList.push(anotherResult)
                })
            });
            Promise.all(promiseList).then(function(promiseItem) {
                childPlacesIds.forEach(function(childPlaceId) {
                    //Do Other Stuff
                });
            });
            resolve(result);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Yea, life sucks sometimes.")
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: @Amir is using es6 with node.js server-side coding pretty common? Whenever I see es6 code I always think of front-end coding that can use es6 so long as it is bundled with babel or some other equivalent.

Comment: Also, thanks for an extremely insightful post! I'll be sure to give credit after the community responds. :)

Comment: @NickPineda Of course. I always use es6 in my node projects. For server side part, node itself supports that and as everything is going to be executed on the server, you shouldn't be worried about support in the client side. And if you are willing to use es6 in client-side, i'd suggest use a transpiler like babeljs.

Comment: @NickPineda I've used es6 in several projects in production. Both on client-side and server-side. It is not very hard to design workflows with `grunt`, `gulp` or similar tools to convert all your es6 files to es5 in order to ship to production.

Comment: You've still got a function expression in there that isn't right.

Comment: @Amir that is awesome that node.js supports es6! I was under the impression that es6 wouldn't come with out of the box support for anything till it became official. I'm excited to learn it now.

Comment: ES6 became official many months ago, nothing supports it 100% yet, but more than enough is there to answer this question.

Comment: @NickPineda You can take a look [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) to see which platform support which feature. But I strongly recommend you to start learning es6 and to use it.

Comment: loganfsmyth,  Amir : Thank you both. Since I've been learning a full stack under the gun I've been unsure about investing into es6. Last meet up I went to it still sounded like it wasn't official yet. I'll be sure to go full es6 from here on out.

Comment: @NickPineda You're welcome. As you are going to start with it, I'd suggest using [`co`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) for async funcitons. It might be a little bit advanced for you right now, but consider it.

Comment: @NickPineda If my post answered your question, please consider upvoting and marking it as the answer for future references. If not, I'd be glad to help more if you need more clarifications.

Comment: @Amir for sure! I will be sure to give give credit soon. There was just a tie with another suggestion that I haven't tried so I didn't know what to accept yet.

Comment: Yea it's a bit of work to use es6 server-side. Just for the record :)

Answer (score 2):

for starters I do not understand you you need a `new Promise..` here, like @loganfsmyth  said, I would simply use arrow functions and reduce the complexity:

```
Killmyself.prototype.fireLeMissles = function (param) {

  return this.anotherFunction(param)
  .then(someList => {
    var promiseList = someList.map( item => this.fireLeMissles(item));
    return Promise.all(promiseList);
  }).then(childPlacesIds => {
    childPlacesIds.forEach(childPlacesId = {
      // .... do something;
    });
    // return something.
  }).catch(err => console.log("Yea, life sucks sometimes."));

}
```

P. S: I am not sure where this `param, someList, childPlacesIds` is coming from, and assumed that you are initializing that `promiseList` as empty array.

Comment: Yes promiseList would be a simple array. I boiled down the original code a lot to try to highlight the point about repetitive bind issue I was dealing with.

Comment: Just make sure to take that `new Promise` point to heart if your original code was still like this.

Comment: This is the correct answer, refactoring out the [deferred antipattern](stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Answer (score 0):

Mido's answer is good, I just wanted to provide an alternative take on it which I think would be useful to know - using promises for the proxies they are:

```
Killmyself.prototype.fireLeMissles = function () {
  let fn = this.anotherFunction(param);
  let others = fn.then(_ => someList.map(this.fireLeMissles, this));
  let othersP = Promise.all(others);
  othersP.then(/* do OtherStuff */);
  return othersP; // or whatever its then returned
}
```

Of course, this gets even easier with a library like bluebird.

Comment: guess you further shorten it to `someList.map(this.fireLeMissles, this)` :)