# javascript how to deep bind an object to a new 'this' value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a value which may be a primitive or a function or an object containing primitives/functions/objects recursively.

Given a `theThis` argument, how can I deep bind all functions which may be inside my value to `theThis` ?

I tried something like:

```
function deepBind(o, ths) { 
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach(key => { 
    const desc=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, key);
    if (typeof desc === "function") Object.defineProperty(o, key, key.bind(ths)); 
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(key).length>0) deepBind(o.key, ths);
  });
}
```

but that failed :(

I looked at some solutions like https://github.com/jonschlinkert/deep-bind/blob/master/index.js but that is not standalone.

I am looking for a `deepBind(val, theThis)` solution which is standalone.
I need the solution to also cover getters and setters.

Thx!

Comment: `I looked at some solutions and made some failed attempts but no luck ...` such as?

Comment: _"or an object containing primitives/functions/objects recursively"_ What do you mean by "recursively"?

Comment: add my attempts

Comment: guest271314 - I mean that val may be an object containing another object as a property that contains a function as a property

Comment: What specifically "failed" at code at Question? What is expected result of `if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(key).length>0) deepBind(o.key, ths);`? Is that what you mean by "recursively"?

Comment: various debugger errors -  it doesn't work - I don't think it was worth posting but the comments asked for it

Comment: @kofifus _"various debugger errors - it doesn't work"_ Consider including the full code, expected result and errors within text of Question. From perspective here, yes, it is worth it to include all relevant code at Question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. "it doesn't work" lacks clarity as to description of what "doesn't work" is and what result should be. How can we reproduce your code?

Comment: thx guest271314, your advice noted

Comment: to point out what's wrong with your code, `key` is a string ... you're using it multiple times as if it's the property you want (you should be using `o[key]` a lot and **never** `o.key` as that refers to the `key` property of `o`) - however, the code you posted, if you fix the usage of `key` you'll end up with infinite recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work as you want

```js
function deepBind(o, ths) {
    Object.entries(o).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (typeof value === "function") {
            // don't use value here :p
         o[key] = o[key].bind(ths);
        }
        if (typeof value === 'object' || typeof value === 'function') {
         deepBind(value, ths);
        }
    });
}
const v = {
    foo:3, 
    fn: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }, 
    obj: { 
        bar: 4,
        fn: function() {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
};
var someThis = {hello: 'world'};
deepBind(v, someThis);
v.fn();
v.obj.fn();
```

Comment: great, will this also cover get/set properties ?

Comment: I haven't the foggiest idea :p

Comment: _"will this also cover get/set properties ?"_ Where are get and set properties mentioned at original Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

something along the lines of :

```
function deepBind (o, thisVal) {

   return Object.keys(o)
      .reduce((res, key) => {

          const v = o[key];
          const tv = typeof v;
          switch (tv) {
              case "object":
                  // should be updated for arrays...
                  if ( v !== null ) {
                      res[key] = deepBind(v, thisVal);
                  } else {
                      res[key] = v;
                  }
                  break;
              case "function":
                  res[key] = v.bind(thisVal);
                  break;
              default:
                  res[key] = v;
                  break;
          }
          return res;

      }, {});

}
```

It recursively copies values from the original objects, binding functions props to the `thisVal`.

Please note that binding recursively does not make a lot of sense because people expect the lexical context to be defined via its call site.